# Maximum number of characters in search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have search field and it doesn't have that typical submit button. It looks like this:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" id="searchbox" onkeypress="return checkLength()"/>
    <span class="btn btn-primary input-group-addon" onclick="checkLength()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
</div>
```

I only added a `span` and not the `input` element for submit button. How do I validate if the user types or inputs not less than 2 characters? If the user types in 1 character only then presses that search button or just hit the enter key, there should be a red error message at the bottom of the search field saying "Keyword should be not less than 2 characters" or something like that.

I tried this code but it's not working:

```
function checkLength(){
    var textbox = document.getElementById("searchbox");
    if(textbox.value.length <= 10 && textbox.value.length >= 2){
        alert("success");
    } else {
        alert("Keyword should be not less than 2 characters");
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
            if (keyCode && keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Need help. Thanks.

EDIT:

After inputting keywords and hit the enter key, the page would redirect to a search results page, but that should be prevented from happening if the inputted keyword does not have 2 or more characters, hence, displaying a red text error message below the search field. How to do it?

Comment: Why you are disabling enter key? Also I see you are using jQuery than why mix it with vanilla js? Avoid using inline event handlers as well.

Comment: sorry I forgot to tell you that this is one of my earliest times using jquery. I didn't know what I was doing. how do I do it right? thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use pattern attribute in HTML5 input, and you can validate the text with just CSS:

```css
.error {
  display: none;
  font: italic medium sans-serif;
  color: red;
}
input[pattern]:required:invalid ~ .error {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="pattern-input" pattern=".{2,}" title="Min 2 characters" required>
  <input type="submit">
  <span class="error">Enter at least two characters</span>
</form>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1stk4gnc/1/)

Note: This would work with all modern browsers, IE9 and earlier doesn't seems to have support for  :invalid, :valid, and :required CSS pseudo-classes till now and Safari have only partial support.

Comment: +1 ... _"IE9 and earlier doesn't seems to have support"_ yes, but there are polyfills ("shivs, shims") for that. Also, HTML5 [`<button type="submit">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) allows any markup which can easily allow the magnifying glass picture to be used.

Comment: this is good but can the error message be shown AFTER hitting enter or the search button?

Comment: can it also validate that when do user doesn't input anything, it display the error message below?

Comment: Yes, I have updated code snippet for validating empty input also.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Validation plugin can be used. it is very simple.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerForm").validate();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id='registerForm' name='registerForm' method='post' action='' >   <p>
   Search <input type='text' name='name' id='name'  minlength="2"     class='required' />
   </p>
</form>
```

[image: sample]

Ref : 
http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.previousElementSibling` to select `span` `.nodeName` to select `input` set `div` `.innerHTML` to empty string `""` or `"Keyword should be not less than 2 characters"` , using `input` event

```js
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");

function checkLength(elem) {
  var el = elem.type === "text" ? elem : elem.previousElementSibling
  , len = el.value.length < 2;
  msg.innerHTML = len ? "Keyword should be not less than 2 characters" : "";
  $(el).one("input", function() {
    checkLength(this)
  })
}
```

```css
#msg {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" id="searchbox" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary input-group-addon" onclick="checkLength(this)" value="X" />
  <div id="msg"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: this is good but can the error message be shown AFTER hitting enter or the search button? and will the error message be hidden again if the user erases his keyword/s?

Comment: the error message still remains when I erase my keyword

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63yywy9a/) that might be close to what you want.

Take a gander and see what you can make of it.

Don't hesitate to ask questions about it.

My best explanation is:

There is an event handler on both the `input` and the `submit` button that test the input's value. Based on the conditions that I have assumed from your question, either a success alert or an error message is shown. The success alert could be replaced with an ajax call or to trigger a form submission.